# How can I make a shader that makes the intersection of two 3D objects transparent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I need a shader that can make intersection of two 3D objects transparent. I know how can I make two sprites intersection area transparent. I use stencil buffer in shader. But I don't know how I can do this in 3d objects. Please help me , thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpImo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can work with 3 objects, and use the stencil buffer to do the effect.

One of the objects will have

```
Stencil{
   Ref valueA
   Comp aways
   Pass replace
}
```

the second:

```
Stencil{
   Ref valueB
   Comp greater
   Pass replace
}
```

the third:

```
Stencil{
   Ref valueB
   Comp less
   Pass replace
}
```

the trick is to put the second and third object in the same position

Answer (score 0):

Sprite shaders are actually 3D shaders just rendered on a single quad. In other words if you know how to do this with sprites then 3D is no different.